# AXStackableViewContainer error after Xcode 14.0 update

Tags: swift, xcode

```
@objc public class AXStackableViewContainer: UIView {

weak var delegate: AXStackableViewContainerDelegate?

/// The inset of the contents of the `StackableViewContainer`.
/// For internal use only.
var contentInset: UIEdgeInsets = .zero

@objc fileprivate(set) var anchorPoint: AXStackableViewContainerAnchorPoint
@objc enum AXStackableViewContainerAnchorPoint: Int {
    case top, bottom
}
```

Error Message:

```
Setter for 'anchorPoint' with Objective-C selector 'setAnchorPoint:' conflicts with setter for 'anchorPoint' from superclass 'UIView' with the same Objective-C selector
```

After the latest Xcode update, this error occurs and cannot be executed. How do I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried change name ``anchorPoint`` into something else like ``thisAnchorPoint``?

Comment: Add some more details. Your post is mostly code.

Answer (score 1):

For `iOS 16.0+` there is a new instance property called `anchorPoint` in `UIView` class. So your compiler is unable to distinguish between them. Changing the name for your property will solve the issue.

For more details about the new `anchorPoint` property read [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/4051982-anchorpoint/).

> The anchor point of the view’s bounds rectangle.